# python sqlite3 trigger before "REPLACE"

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

The scenario is:

I have 2 tables: today_version (storing everyday latest info) and history_version (**whenever before a record in today_version is changed, the old record will first be inserted into history_version for backup, and get changed in today_version**).

They are created by:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS today_version (
region TEXT,
instance TEXT,
version TEXT,
last_update_time TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (region, version)
)     

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS history_version (
region TEXT,
instance TEXT,
version TEXT,
last_update_time TEXT
)
```

For everyday, there are 2 possible changes in today_version: insert a new record (PRIMARY KEY not found), or, update the version & last_update_time (PRIMARY KEY exists). So my python/pandas code here becomes:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
query = '''insert or replace into today_version (region, instance, version, last_update_time) values (?,?,?,?,?)'''
conn.executemany(query, df.to_records(index=False))
```

This part is valid and I have checked in terminal by:

```
$ sqlite3
$ > select * from today_version;
...... (record)
```

Then, I would like to use TRIGGER to achieve the part:  (**whenever a record in today_version is changed, it will be inserted into history_version for backup**).

However, from [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), only "insert", "delete", "update" is supported for trigger, where "replace" is actually first delete this row then insert a new one.

May I ask that how can I achieve this requirement? Currently I am trying out the following but didn't work (gives out empty table):

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_history BEFORE DELETE ON today_version
WHEN new.version != old.version
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO history_version (market, instance, version, last_update_time) VALUES (old.market, old.instance, old.version, old.last_update_time);
END;
```

Comment: You can only use old in delete triggers, not new.  The notes on REPLACE conflict resolution [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) might be useful.

Comment: Thx Shawn. But I dont think this will work since replace always happen if a primay key constraint is found. This cannot distinguish using the prev version or today's version has been changed.